# SQL Query To Delete the Top Rows and 1st column

Tags: mysql, sql

Need Help I am trying to write a query to delete the first top row and the whole first column, kindly note that my first row and first column is null and i am struggling to write a query to delete my first null row and first null column

```
select * from MyTable
Delete 
From MyTable where F1 =1 and F1 =1
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "first top row" in a SQL table.  Tables represent *unordered* sets, so there is only a "first" row if a column specifies the ordering.

Comment: What is `F1` ???

Comment: And you cannot remove a column without altering your table.

Comment: @ bill the first row is completely blank and it shows F1 on sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't delete a column with a DELETE command.  You will need to ALTER the table to delete the column.

Comment: I just want to delete the row 1 as it is a blank and the column 1 as well

Comment: @ramon:  Deleting a column is a significant modification of a table's structure.  Hence the `alter` keyword.  Deleting a row is routine, but many database designers prefer not to delete rows but instead modifying some "status" field to set it as *not active* or some other such methodology.

Comment: My first row is null how can i remove my first row?